# Comparison of 2 code chunks - what's the difference?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I was working on some code trying to resolve a bug. This was the original chunk of code:

```
passrate = 90
for child in sorted_children:
    if child.passrate >= passrate:
        return child
return None
```

This code was buggy and this is it's fix:

```
passrate = 90
for child in sorted_children:
    if child.passrate() >= passrate:
        return child
return None
```

The only difference is the added parenthesis. So, `child` is a class and `passrate()` is it's method which lazy-loads and returns it's `__passrate` value. If it's not calculated yet, it calculates it before returning it.

When I used the debugger to see what was causing the problem, I saw that sometimes when `passrate()` was executing it was like code execution somehow ended up in a completely wrong instance of child's class.

I know that without the parenthesis a pointer to the function is returned, but as it's done inside a logical operation, the function should be executed immediately afterwards so the final result should be the same for both chunks of code. And sometimes it indeed was. But sometimes it wasn't for some reason, always in the same iterated child in every execution of the code.

If someone could explain what could have caused the problem, I'd appreciate it very much.

EDIT:
Thanks everyone for helping. The old code was clearly wrong. I have no idea how it worked at all in the past.

Comment: "as it's done inside a logical operation, the function should be executed immediately afterwards" I don't think this is correct.

Comment: "I know that without the parenthesis a pointer to the function is returned, but as it's done inside a logical operation, the function should be executed immediately afterwards" - nope. That doesn't happen. I don't know why you would expect it to happen.

Comment: If that doesn't happen, then what does happen in the first chunk of code?

Comment: If it looked like the method was being called anyway, the most likely explanation is that you looked at the wrong part of your code's execution and mistook it for the part you were interested in. What actually happens is that Python attempts to return a consistent but meaningless result for the comparison. The method is not executed.

Comment: Well, I did use the debugger and as I was iterating through the loop, in the comparison line the `passrate()` method was executed each time. But sometimes on the wrong instance for some reason, as I've said.

Comment: Perhaps you made the method a property (in which case, the second code example shouldn't work), or you accidentally wrote this function twice and you're looking at a copy Python doesn't use.

Comment: No, it is a regular method and it's not written twice. As I've already said, I didn't just look at the code, I had my debugger running and I was executing it line by line. The method was executed with the first chunk of code.

Answer (score 1):

I think, as per python's rule if it's method, then it should be called with braces. If it's a property then you can call without braces as below:

```
class Hello(object):
    @property
    def hi(self):
        print "hello"

    def hifunc(self):
        print "Hi function"

h=Hello()
print h.hi
print h.hifunc
print h.hifunc()
```

Output:

```
hello
None
<bound method Hello.hifunc of <__main__.Hello object at 0x0000000002B99358>>
Hi function
None
```

None is printed as my example function returns nothing. In your case, when you call with braces, your return values from function used for comparison.